# How to get data into NSArray from NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsdictionary

i am getting following error while getting data from dictionary

"**-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4fbb80**"

**here is my code**

```
  NSDictionary *dic = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:class.returnData error:nil];

  MyGiftsarray = [[dic objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"gifts"];


  for (NSDictionary *element in MyGiftsarray) {

  [MyGiftsnamearray addObject:[element objectForKey:@"name"]];

  [MyGiftsChkarray addObject:[element objectForKey:@"chk"]];

   [MyGiftsIdarray addObject:[element objectForKey:@"id"]];

   [MyGiftsApprovedarray addObject:[element objectForKey:@"approved"]];

   [MyGiftsisCompletedarray addObject:[element objectForKey:@"completed"]];

 }
```

**this is NSDictionary from which i try to get data.**
MyGiftsDict->(

```
 {
    Appliedpoint = 500;
    Requiredpoint = 5000;
    approved = N;
    chk = 50;
    completed = 0;
    id = 66;
    name = "1-800Flowers.com";
},
    {
    Appliedpoint = 85;
    Requiredpoint = 2500;
    approved = N;
    chk = 25;
    completed = 0;
    id = 71;
    name = "Bath Body Works";
},
    {
    Appliedpoint = 5;
    Requiredpoint = 2500;
    approved = N;
    chk = 25;
    completed = 0;
    id = 75;
    name = "Buca di Beppo";
},
    {
    Appliedpoint = 36;
    Requiredpoint = 2500;
    approved = N;
    chk = 25;
    completed = 0;
    id = 66;
    name = "1-800Flowers.com";
},
    {
    Appliedpoint = 25;
    Requiredpoint = 5000;
    approved = N;
    chk = 50;
    completed = 0;
    id = 90;
    name = "Jelly Belly";
},
    {
    Appliedpoint = 120;
    Requiredpoint = 500;
    approved = N;
    chk = 5;
    completed = 0;
    id = 129;
    name = "Amazon.com";
}
```

)

Comment: @janusfidel that's wrong - the for-in loop on NSDictionaries iterates over keys, not objects.

Comment: yup. thats why I removed the comment.

Comment: I think you haven't allocated "MyGiftsarray" in your .m file. Try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating in wrong manner-
Use -

```
MyGiftsDict = [[dic objectForKey:@"response"] objectForKey:@"gifts"];
```

And then iterate over dictionary step by step.
You need to use something like -

```
for(NSString *key in [MyGiftsDict allKeys])
{
    [MyGiftsnamearray addObject:[MyGiftsDict objectForKey:key]];
}
```

Comment: hey i am getting multi time value in array.

Comment: Now you are getting an array, and inside that array each item is a dictionary.So for for loop with iterate over an array with dictionary object and second for loop will iterate over dictionary like i had done above. Hope its clear.

Answer (score 0):

Gifts is an NSDictionary in itself. **It's not an NSArray!** You don't need that for loop. Use simply

```
[MyGiftsNameArray addObject:[MyGiftsArray objectForKey:@"name"];
```

et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will need the `for`cycle.